# asp.net get value from Jquery UI dialog back to first form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, postback, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the below JQuery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $("#no-email-popup").dialog(
             {
                 autoOpen: false,
                 buttons: {
                     "ok": function() {
                     alert($('#new_email').val());
                     alert(window.top.$("#new_email_label.").val());
                   //  alert(window.top.$("#<%= new_email_label.ClientID %>").val());
                         $(this).dialog("close");

                     },
                     "cancel": function() {
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                     }
                 }

             }
        );
     });
</script>
```

And and modal asp.net is

```
<div id="no-email-popup">
<label>Enter Email: </label>
<input type="text" id="new_email" />
</div>
```

I want to get the value from Pop up back to to asp.net page and assign to label there

```
<asp:Label ID="new_email_label" runat="server">test top window label</asp:Label>
```

I found out that I cannot change the value of this label even

Please help how to get value to top asp.net page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.val()` on a `<label/>` won't give you the inner html of said label. You would need to use `.html()` to retrieve it, or `.html("something")` to set it.

Answer (score 0):

after (or instead) of your `alert`s, try: `$("#new_email_label").val($("#new_email").val());`

Comment: well, parent label is not even defined to able to assign it, i cannot access the intial value to change it